# Combine multiple calcs using union

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, union

I have multiple calculations that use union and i am trying to combine them so i can load them into a new table on the same row.

Below is an example of the calculations, i will have 8 in total. I want to load the results to a new summary table via a stored proc but I am not sure on how to proceed in terms of combining/loading these calcs.

The summary table will contain 8 calc columns, and the name column and a load date. It will only ever contain 1 row as the data is deleted and reloaded throughout the day.

```
--current day

select Name, count(cast (id as int))  as current_day from (
    select Name,id from [Table1]
    where CONVERT(DATE, dte_Uploaded) = CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    union all
    select Name,id from from [Table2]
    where CONVERT(DATE, dte_Uploaded) = CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

) x group by Name



--current week


select Name, count(cast (id as int))  as current week from (
    select Name,id from [Table1]
    where DATEDIFF(ww, dte_Uploaded, GETDATE()) = 0
    union all
    select Name,id from from [Table2]
    where DATEDIFF(ww, dte_Uploaded, GETDATE()) = 0


) x group by  Name


--current month


select Name, count(cast (id as int))   as current_month from (
    select Name,id from [Table1]
    where DATEDIFF(m, dte_Uploaded, GETDATE()) = 0
    union all
    select Name,id from from [Table2]
    where DATEDIFF(m, dte_Uploaded, GETDATE()) = 0


) x group by  Name
```

Comment: `from from` syntax error.

Comment: `current week` syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have better performance and improved readability if you calculate proper date ranges in advance and use *conditional aggregation* to calculate your counts.

When calculating date ranges, it is common to calculate an *inclusive* start date and an *exclusive* end date (00:00:00 at the start of the day afterwards). This nicely handles date/time fields without having to truncate potentially indexed column values.

*Conditional aggregation* combines an aggregate function (in this case `COUNT()`) with a `CASE` expression that either includes or excludes each value from the aggregation. For `COUNT()` the `THEN 1` rows are counted, while the implicit `ELSE NULL` rows are not.

Try something like:

```
-- Day, week, and month ranges. (End dates are exclusive.)
DECLARE @today      DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
DECLARE @day_from   DATE = @today
DECLARE @day_to     DATE = DATEADD(day, 1, @day_from)
DECLARE @week_from  DATE = DATETRUNC(week, @today)
DECLARE @week_to    DATE = DATEADD(week, 1, @week_from)
DECLARE @month_from DATE = DATETRUNC(month, @today)
DECLARE @month_to   DATE = DATEADD(month, 1, @month_from)

-- Overall range (to limit initial data retrieval)
DECLARE @range_from DATE = LEAST(@week_from, @month_from)
DECLARE @range_to   DATE = GREATEST(@week_to, @month_to)

SELECT
    Name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN dt >= @day_from   AND dt < @day_to   THEN 1 END) AS current_day,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN dt >= @week_from  AND dt < @week_to  THEN 1 END) AS current_week,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN dt >= @month_from AND dt < @month_to THEN 1 END) AS current_month
FROM (
    SELECT Name, dte_Uploaded AS dt
    FROM Table1
    WHERE dte_Uploaded >= @range_from AND dte_Uploaded < @range_to
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, dte_Uploaded AS dt
    FROM Table2
    WHERE dte_Uploaded >= @range_from AND dte_Uploaded < @range_to
) X
GROUP BY Name
```

If dte_Uploaded is indexed, the above will efficiently retrieve only those rows needed for the current calculation, rather than a less-efficient table scan.

If you are using older versions of SQL server that do not support the `DATETRUNC()`, `LEAST()`, and `GREATEST()` functions, the following alternate date calculations can be used:

```
-- Day, week, and month ranges. (End dates are exclusive.)
DECLARE @today      DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
DECLARE @day_from   DATE = @today
DECLARE @day_to     DATE = DATEADD(day, 1, @today)
DECLARE @week_from  DATE = DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, @today), @today)
DECLARE @week_to    DATE = DATEADD(week, 1, @week_from)
DECLARE @month_from DATE = DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(@today), @today)
DECLARE @month_to   DATE = DATEADD(month, 1, @month_from)

-- Overall range (to limit initial data retrieval)
DECLARE @range_from DATE = CASE WHEN @week_from < @month_from THEN @week_from ELSE @month_from END
DECLARE @range_to   DATE = CASE WHEN @week_to > @month_to THEN @week_to ELSE @month_to END
```

Depending how your site defines the start of a week, the week ranges might need to be tweaked.

Comment: Thanks T N! This looks to be working, there are an additonal couple of calcs that are required; current year, previous day, previous week, previous month, previous year. What date variables would be required for these under the declare statements?

Comment: Well, the current @year_ from can be calculated using the same technique as calculating the start f the current week or month - either `DATETRUNC(...)` or (for older SQL server versions) `DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dayofyear, @today), @today)`. Previous from-dates can be calculated using `DATEADD(..., -1, ...)` against the other dates. Previous to-dates would be equal to the corresponding current from-dates.

Comment: The overall range would also need adjustment. I believe that `@range_from` could just be set to `@previous_year_from`, as none of the other ranges could precede that. `@range_to` would be `GREATEST(@week_to, @year_to)` or the equivalent `CASE` expression.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give this a go, appreciate the help!

Comment: This worked a treat, thanks again T N, you are an absolute legend!

Answer (score 1):

If target table contains only one row, I presume that each of queries you posted also contains only one row. Because, if they don't, how will you know which row to pick?

Anyway: one option is to use your current queries as CTEs (common table expressions; a *new* way to use subqueries), cross join them and fetch columns you're interested in.

For example:

```
with 
current_day as(
select Name, count(cast (id as int))  as current_day from (
    select Name,id from [Table1]
    where CONVERT(DATE, dte_Uploaded) = CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    union all
    select Name,id from from [Table2]
    where CONVERT(DATE, dte_Uploaded) = CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
) x group by Name),
current_week as(

select Name, count(cast (id as int))  as current_week from (
    select Name,id from [Table1]
    where DATEDIFF(ww, dte_Uploaded, GETDATE()) = 0
    union all
    select Name,id from from [Table2]
    where DATEDIFF(ww, dte_Uploaded, GETDATE()) = 0
) x group by  Name),
current month as
(
select Name, count(cast (id as int))   as current_month from (
    select Name,id from [Table1]
    where DATEDIFF(m, dte_Uploaded, GETDATE()) = 0
    union all
    select Name,id from from [Table2]
    where DATEDIFF(m, dte_Uploaded, GETDATE()) = 0
) x group by  Name)
select a.name, a.current_day, b.current_week, c.current_month
from current_day a cross join current_week b cross join current_month c;
```

If cross join won't work, then you should know how to properly join results returned by each CTE.

---

Finally, how to insert values into the target table? Like this:

```
insert into target (name, current_day, current_week, current_month)
with current_day as (the whole query posted above goes here)
select a.name, a.current_day, b.current_week, c.current_month
from current_day a cross join current_week b cross join current_month c
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'm getting an incorrect syntax error on line 19  with the cte on the current month row. Wonder if im missing something?

Comment: I got the cte to return data but the cross join does not work as not all the name values are returning and its giving me multiple rows for current day and current week counts

Comment: Right; that's what I said: I *presumed* that every query returns only one row because target table - as you said - always contains only one row. If you have multiple rows per each query, how do you know which row to take? Apparently, there are several names and their *counts*. What is desired result, then? How will you make sure that target table contains only one row?

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, this just didn't suit my data but this code is definately a great help to me for future SQL, appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome.